# Принятие сообщений в личных сообщениях discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Увидел как чужой бот принимает сообщения из личных сообщений, хочу также.
Суть: пишешь допустим "лол" в личные сообщения боту, он все принимает, а если написал в канале на сервере, то бот игнорил. Короче чтобы принимал сообщения и откликался только в лс. Использовать нужно `async def on_message(message)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    if not message.guild:
        await message.author.send("Необходимое ответное сообщение")


bot.run('token')
```

Если возникнут вопросы - задавайте. Код проверил, работает.
В случае, если необходимо сделать ответ на конкретную фразу или слово, просто добавьте ещё одно условие с проверкой этого слова или фразы.

Comment: огромное спасибо!!!!!!!!

Comment: Рад, если смог помочь. Удачи в разработке Ваших идей!
Если ответ смог помочь, буду признателен, если выберете его, как ответ :)